# How do I display the sorted value based on their properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How do I display the sorted value based on their properties. Example, I want to just display the likes, making back into an object.
so i can use as a properties.

Sorry for the Edit, this is the updated edit and working simulation.

Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

```js
var CatObj=[];
        var CatimgLikes=[1,4,6,10];
        var CatPostBy=["John","Anne","Simon","Sifu"];
        var CatURLArray=["url1","url2","url3","url4"];
        
            //console.log(CatObj[i]);
            //console.log(Cat);
        

        for(var i=0;i<CatimgLikes.length;i++)
        {

            CatObj[i] = {Likes: CatimgLikes[i], postedByName: CatPostBy[i],imgURL: CatURLArray[i]};
            //console.log(instaObj[i]);
            //console.log(instaObj);
        
            //console.log(instaObj.Likes);
        }


        var byLikes = CatObj.slice(0);
        byLikes.sort(function(a,b) 
        {
            return a.Likes - b.Likes;
        });
        byLikes.sort();
        console.log(byLikes);
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't run--please read the error message and correct the code.

Comment: Hi, this is just an example of my sorting in which when i run this program. It will display in the log sorted array.

Comment: Do `console.log(JSON.stringify(byLikes));` and add result to question

Answer (score 0):

Does this example get at your question?

```js
var byLikes = [
  { name: 'herman', Like: 'milk' },
  { name: 'tabitha', Like: 'catnip' }
];

byLikes.sort(sortByLike);

byLikes.forEach(function (cat) {
  console.log(cat.Like);
});
 
function sortByLike(a, b) {
  var result = 0;
  if(a.Like > b.Like) { result = 1; }
  if(b.Like > a.Like) { result = -1; }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: i already updated the working code snippet. How do i get the sorted information into an object?

Comment: Its working but how do we put the object in the render. This are the sample codes .res.render('reload', {urls: getPostedName, imglikes: getPostedName, postName: getPostedName});

Comment: I recommend MDN for explanations about JS. Here's something on classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes